# How do I select the child tag when specific tag is encountered?

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

How do I grab the value of the tags `<lle:lat>` and `<lle:long>` for every `<lle:tweet>` tag encountered? The current C# code only get the `<lle:lat>` and `<lle:long>` value for the first `<lle:tweet>` tag and it is repeated. Without using XPath, just LINQ to XML only

Because there's only 2 `<lle:tweet>` tags in the xml file

Expected output:

```
Latitude:123
Longitude:456
Latitude:434
Longitude:554
```

Current output:

```
Latitude:123
Longitude:456
Latitude:123
Longitude:456
Latitude:123
Longitude:456
```

Below is the XML file:

```
 <soapenv:Letter xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope" soapenv:encodingStyle="http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-encoding" >
            <soapenv:Body xmlns:lle="http://www.aab.org/lifelogevents" >
                <lle:Event>
                    <lle:eventid>ID1</lle:eventid>
                    <lle:tweet>
                        <lle:text>This is some tweet in my day</lle:text>
                        <lle:location>
                            <lle:lat>123</lle:lat>
                            <lle:long>456</lle:long>
                        </lle:location>
                    </lle:tweet>                              
                </lle:Event>
                <lle:Event>
                    <lle:eventid>ID2</lle:eventid>
                        <lle:instagram-post-update>
                            <lle:text>This is some status update in my day</lle:text>
                            <lle:location>
                              <lle:lat>789</lle:lat>
                              <lle:long>987</lle:long>
                            </lle:location>
                        </lle:instagram-post-update>
                    </lle:Event>
                <lle:Event>
                    <lle:eventid>ID3</lle:eventid>
                    <lle:tweet>
                        <lle:text>This is some tweet in my day</lle:text>
                        <lle:location>
                            <lle:lat>434</lle:lat>
                            <lle:long>554</lle:long>
                        </lle:location>
                    </lle:tweet>                              
                </lle:Event>
            </soapenv:Body>
        </soapenv:Letter>
```

This is my C# code so far:

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load(@"C:\Users\JACK\source\repos\LINQ_Learn\LINQ_Learn\xmlFile.xml");
                XNamespace lle = "http://www.aab.org/lifelogevents";
                XNamespace soapenv = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope";

var tweetElements = from tweetTag in xmldoc.Descendants(nlle + "Event")
                                select tweetTag.Element(nlle + "tweet");

foreach (var twitElem in tweetElements)
            {          
                var lati = xmldoc.Descendants(nlle + "tweet")
                            .Descendants(nlle + "lat")
                            .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                var lng = xmldoc.Descendants(nlle + "tweet")
                            .Descendants(nlle + "long")
                            .FirstOrDefault()?.Value;

                Console.WriteLine("Latitude:{0}", lati);
                Console.WriteLine("Longitude:{0}", lng);
            }
```

Comment: What is the problem? I get the lats and lons when I run your code.

Comment: By the way, when working with SOAP you typically work with a generated client and you don't need to be concerned with xml. Is there a reason you are not working with a soap client for this service? Or... using their REST api?

Comment: @Crowcoder it only display the first "tweet" tag latitude and longitude and its repeated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could project the lat/lon pairs in one statement by drilling down from `tweet`s:

```
XDocument xmldoc = XDocument.Load("...file here...");
XNamespace nlle = "http://www.aab.org/lifelogevents";
XNamespace soapenv = "http://www.w3.org/2001/12/soap-envelope";
    
var latlons = from tweetTag in xmldoc.Descendants(nlle + "tweet")
   .Descendants(nlle + "location") 
   select new { Lat = tweetTag.Element(nlle + "lat").Value, Lon = tweetTag.Element(nlle + "long").Value};
```

Comment: Should be : from tweetTag in xmldoc.Descendants().Where(x => x.name.LocalName == "location")

Comment: @jdweng since I'm using the namespace I don't need "LocalName". The code works.

Comment: You are not the OP and didn't provide the vapor code that contains the namespace.

Comment: @jdweng I thought it was obvious if you read the question, but ok, I'll edit

Comment: @Crowcoder the code selected all the lats and lons, it takes in the `<lle:instagram-post-update>`  lats and lons.